# Can a scalar valued function be a vector valued function?

Tags: functions

Suppose $r(x,y) = x\,y$. Apparently this can't be a vector valued function, because it doesn't have enough rows/ columns to output vectors in the x-y-plane, right?

But what about $r(x) = x^2$ ? How to tell whether it is vector valued or scalar valued? Maybe it's nonsense because in my mind this would give a straight x-line (1 dimensional space).

Comment: What does $\;x^2\;$ even mean when it is a vector with two or more entries?

Comment: Yea, a little unclear. Either it's a 1x1 vector or a scalar.

Comment: But if it is a $\;1\times1\;$ vector then we're in $\;\Bbb R^1=\Bbb R\;$ and we have a rather usual, boring real function....It is though a parabola, not a straight line.

Comment: Well if it's $x^2\,e_x$, where $e_x$ is the unit vector in x direction it's just a movement along the x-axis. Probably that's the difference between scalar and vectorial.